# SQL query problem: LIKE operation isn't working in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

mom_status condition not worked .......please help me

this is SQL query

SELECT * 
FROM `create_mom` 
WHERE
 ( mom_status = '0') and 
 (emp_id LIKE '%,$emp_id'
 or emp_id LIKE '%,$emp_id,%'
 or emp_id LIKE '$emp_id,%'
 or emp_id LIKE '$emp_id')

Comment: You forgot to ask a question (and to describe your problem).

Comment: Mixing ORs and ANDs without using brackets does quite often end in disaster. Put some brackets around what you want to group together. `Name = 'John' OR (Name = 'Tim' AND Age = 20)` is different to `(Name = 'John' OR Name = 'Tim') AND Age = 20` - which one do you think `Name = 'John' OR Name = 'Tim' AND Age = 20` is?

Comment: So. What do you want us to help with?

Comment: Brackets are great when mixing AND with OR.

Comment: user_id = $emp_id and also emp_id = $emp_id? Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have `OR` and `AND` in `WHERE` clause, you should always use parenthesis to execute the conditions based on priority :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `create_mom` 
WHERE (user_id='".$emp_id."' and mom_status = '0') and 
      (emp_id LIKE '%,$emp_id' or emp_id LIKE '%,$emp_id,%' or emp_id LIKE '$emp_id,%' or emp_id LIKE '$emp_id')
```

Comment: How do you know for sure that the brackets are supposed to be placed there?

Comment: thanks sir its worked

Comment: thanks sir its worked

Comment: thanks sir its worked